# What does sender is in prepareForSegue:sender call?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Suppose I perform a segue change when a button is tapped as given in the code below.

```
- (IBAction)btnTapped:(id)sender {   
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
}
```

I'm wondering the purpose of the "sender" part. Does it make difference if I make the call with the parameter `sender:sender`, `sender:@{@"foo",@"bar"}` or `sender:nil` ??

Edit1:

Can I get this `sender` at the destination ViewController for instance at `ViewDidLoad()` function?

Comment: Yes, you can send and sender object you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:):

> sender:
>
> The object that you want to use to initiate the segue.
>
> This object is made available **for informational purposes** during the actual segue.

If you want to use `sender` object in the target `UIViewController`, use [`prepareForSegue:sender:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:) method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Can I get this `sender` at the destination ViewController for instance at ViewDidLoad function?

Answer (score 0):

The sender attribute, no matter the method using it, is made so you can easily retrieve informations from an anterior view, just by explicit casting (id)sender to (MyAnteriorView *)sender.